# Is it a sin to be homophobic?

Tags: sin, homosexuality

Salam, I don't think I need to explain my question further. But Allah doesn't approve of homosexuality and doesn't want us to support it, however is it ok to hate lgbtq? For example me and my brother always make fun of them and make jokes (we don't actually go up to people psychically who are lgbtq and bully them we joke about it between ourselves). Sometimes tho we'd troll online in a game and I'd have my username like lgbtq=trash or something. But I do actually hate lgbtq, they're always stubborn and annoying, some are even mad that not everyone supports which really pisses me off. Is Allah angry at me for being a homophobic? Does He want me to just leave them alone and keep quiet about it? Or does He not care that I'm trying to prove the sinners wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Muslims, we are told to respect everyone and to not mock people for who they are, regardless of what they do is haram.

I'm not saying we should accept the LGBT community, but we have no right to disrespect them because they're still humans. It doesn't matter if you're not physically abusing/verbally abusing them, disrespect is shown in many ways.

You're a Muslim. You're set to be an example for mankind.

> **Is Allah angry at me for being a homophobic? Does He want me to just leave them alone and keep quiet about it? Or does He not care that I'm trying to prove the sinners wrong?**

Allah says in the Qur'an 7:199:

> (O Prophet), take forgiveness (as your habit), enjoin virtue, and ignore the ignorant.

The Prophet Muhammad (saws) said:

> “Be kind, for whenever kindness becomes part of something, it beautifies it. Whenever it is taken from something, it leaves it tarnished.” 
>  **-Saheeh Al Muslim, Book #32, Hadith #6274**

The Prophet (saws) also said:

> "Speak good, or remain silent"

> **Or does He not care that I'm trying to prove the sinners wrong?**

How exactly are you *proving* the sinners wrong? By mocking them? Disrespecting them?

In a way, what you're doing is coming close to bullying. How would you feel if someone had the username "Islam=trash"? Angry, upset, and bad right?

Allah doesn’t approve of Him having a son, does that mean we have to mock Christians?
Of course not.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is although it’s haram to be a homosexual Allah doesn’t say to go and discriminate or mock them. I’d just be quiet and ignore them as it isn’t right for you to mock them even if what they do is haram. Leave it to the almighty